# Cypress - Visit a URL obtained from a 3rd party(email)

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my test, I want to visit a URL that is sent in an email. I can successfully save the URL in a variable, but am unable to get cypress to go to that URL. I keep getting the below error. I don't fully understand cypress being "promise-like", so I'm not sure how to resolve the issue

> Uncaught (in promise) CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned
>   a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands
>   in that promise.
>
> The command that returned the promise was:
>
> > cy.get()
>
> The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:
>
> > cy.request()
>
> Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to
>   wrap them or return your own promise.
>
> Cypress will resolve your command with whatever the final Cypress
>   command yields.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("clickForgotPwdLink", (emailaddress) => {
    const MailosaurClient = require('mailosaur');
    const client = new MailosaurClient('1234');
    let latestEmail;
    var emailLower = emailaddress.toLowerCase();
    client.messages.search('abc', {
        sentTo: emailLower
    }).then((results) => {
        latestEmail = results.items[0];
        let email = latestEmail.id;
        client.messages.get(email)
            .then((newlink) => {
                var forgotpwd = newlink.html.links[0].href;
                console.log(forgotpwd)
                cy.request(''+forgotpwd+'');
            })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to face this today.
If you are getting a raw body response (string) you have to get the link in this way:

```
            const links = body.split("href=http://my.url.com");
            var activation_link = links[0].match(/\bhttp?:\/\/\S+/);
            activation_link= activation_link[0].replace('"','')
            cy.visit(activation_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just as simple as removing all the quotes and plusses from the cy.request? That is how we use a stored url and that works. But that stored url doesn't come from an email but from an element on the page

Comment: Removing those will result in the same error. I think the root of the problem is that Cypress doesn't like me calling out to the mail api, and then running a cypress command. I'm unsure how to get around this. I would think this is a pretty common test that needs to be automated, so Cypress should have some type of solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried like you but Cypress doens't allowed.
You have to do it via cy.request() to Mailosaur API.

Try something like this:

```
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://mailosaur.com/api/messages/search',
  auth: {
    username: 'API_key',
  },
  body: {
    sentTo: 'yourEmail',
  },
  qs: {
    server: 'yourServer',
    page: 0,
    itemsPerPage: 50,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using Cypress recorder which email testing embedded in it. I like how Preflight generates cypress code and lets you test emails.

I'd recommend checking out https://cypress.preflight.com/

I've dealt with cy.request before. It's a little cumbersome to get the emails

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31358925)